# Input string was not in a correct format Error: Use value from dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code keep show error:Input string was not in a correct format.
[image]

Refer below for my code.

```
DropDownList qty = (DropDownList)dlDiscountedProducts.Items[i].FindControl("ddlQuantity");         
int cartQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(qty.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim());
```

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: you can debug and see what `SelectedValue.ToString()` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check empty before use Parse. I hope it will help you.

```
int cartQuantity = 0;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qty.SelectedValue.Trim()))
{
    if(qty.SelectedValue.Trim().All(char.IsDigit))
    {
        cartQuantity = int.Parse(qty.SelectedValue.Trim());
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Int32.TryParse

```
int cartQuantity ;
if (Int32.TryParse(qty.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim(), out cartQuantity ))
{
    //continue using cartQuantity 
}
```